# Unknown group "pcscd" after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: 20.04, log

After upgrading to 20.04 I find the following warning (19 times) in Gnome-Logs:

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libifd-cyberjack6.rules:24 Unknown group 'pcscd', ignoring
```

I found this explanation of the problem  https://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2011/11/pcscd-auto-start-using-systemd.html but it is not clear to me what I need to do to not have the warning. I would like the card reader to start when I plug it in, as in other Ubuntu versions.

Comment: If the error is just " Unknown group 'pcscd' " you can add the "pcscd" group via [addgroup](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-adduser-addgroup-command/) and if necessary , add your user to that group.

Comment: Did you use PC/SC with REINER SCT cyberJack USB chipcard reader on previous Ubuntu version?

Comment: @ N0rbert Definitely. I don't use it very often but I definitely used it with 19.04 and probably 19.10. I have just upgrade from 19.10 and never had this warning with either of the two mentioned versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like both [`libifd-cyberjack6` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=60-libifd-cyberjack6.rules) which is

> REINER SCT cyberJack USB chipcard reader user space driver

with dependency on [`pcscd` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/pcscd) which is

> Middleware to access a smart card using PC/SC (daemon side)

did not created a corresponding group.

So if you really use PC/SC with REINER SCT cyberJack USB chipcard reader you can proceed with manual group creation by

```
sudo groupadd -g 145 pcscd
```

I got the 145 GID value on old system which has `pcscd` package already installed.

If you do not use smartcards - simply remove the corresponding package

```
sudo apt-get remove libifd-cyberjack6
```

---

Also I have reported [bug 1881142](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pcsc-lite/+bug/1881142) to LaunchPad about clean installation of corresponding packages on fresh 20.04 LTS system.